# Event onclick on <td> and <tr>

Tags: javascript

I have an onclick event in a table both on a `<td>` and `<tr>` elements. I need when the user clicks on the specific column (`<td>`), the `<tr>` event won't be triggered, only the `<td>` one.

How to do it ?

Example :

HTML :

```
<tr onclick='trclick();'>
<td>Column 1</td>
<td>Column 2</td>
<td onclick='tdclick();'>Column 3</td>
</tr>
```

JS :

```
function trclick(){console.log('tr clicked')};
function tdclick(){console.log('td clicked')};
```

When the user clicks on 'Column 3', both events are triggered, but i want only `tdclick()` to be triggered.

Comment: You realize Column 3 is a child of tr , right ?

Comment: can you make sure that the semicolon `;` is not in the HTML ? but in `onclick` attribute

Comment: Check the `cellIndex` of a clicked `td`, and if it is `2`, then stop propagation.

Comment: @Teemu only have to stop the propagation in `tdclick`

Comment: Just fixed it @Hacketo

Comment: How to stop propagation @Hacketo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need to do is to stop the propagation of the parent event when a child is clicked, it's easy done in jQuery, but naively you need to do a little more work:

```
function trclick(){
    console.log('tr clicked')
};

function tdclick(e){ 
    if (!e) var e = window.event;                // Get the window event
    e.cancelBubble = true;                       // IE Stop propagation
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();  // Other Broswers
    console.log('td clicked');
};
```

Note, for Firefox you need to pass a `event` parameter:

```
<td onclick='tdclick(event)'>Column 3</td>
```

Comment: why are you referring to jQuery ?

Comment: @Hacketo Because jQuery has their [own event to handle propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/). Which tends to be easier to work with compared to doing it naively.

Answer (score 6):

You need to stop the propagation of the event.
to access the event object you need to use it as parameter of your function `tdclick`

```js
function trclick(){console.log('tr clicked')};

function tdclick(event){
    console.log('td clicked'); 
    event.stopPropagation()
};
```

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr onclick='trclick();'>
<td>Column 1</td>
<td>Column 2</td>
<td onclick='tdclick(event);'>Column 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use el in your function input and pass the variable to it, in every where you wanna call it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function colorChanger(el){
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#007d00';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr onclick="colorChanger(this);">
      <td onclick="colorChanger(this);">click me</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

All javascript events are invoked with an "event" object in the first argument. This object have a "stopPropagation" method, which prevent listeners of the same event on higher hierarchical DOM nodes to be triggered.

There's an example just like yours at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

In your example, you could just stop propagation on "tdclick":

```js
function tdclick(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('td clicked')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this method:

```
<td style='cursor: pointer;' tdclick(event);'></td>
```

then JS

```
<script>
    tdclick(){
     //do something...
    }
</script>
```